# Z-index doesn't overlap to the same DIVs

Tags: html, css, z-index, overlapping

The problem is the overlapping yellow blocks– they should always be on top.

Yes, I know I can draw the yellow blocks and set them using absolute positioning. But... Can I solve this without changing the HTML structure?

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/pitonoved/pen/WNRqQaW)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.green {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
.blue {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">
    <div class="blue">
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">
    <div class="blue">
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">
    <div class="nested">
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Can I solve this without changing the HTML structure?" Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<div class="container1">
      <div class="green">
        <div class="blue">
          <div class="yellow"></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="green">
        <div class="blue">
          <div class="yellow"></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="green">
        <div class="nested">
          <div class="yellow"></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  .container1 {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      z-index: 8;
    }
    .container2 {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      z-index: 7;
    }
    .container3 {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      z-index: 6;
    }
    .green {
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background: green;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .blue {
      position: relative;
      background: blue;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    .yellow {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 30px;
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      background: yellow;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
```

I am so sorry but have just found a solution to that problem a little bit by changing the HTML code.
Can you explain about the absolute position? to which parent element do you want to set yellow block?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This did not completely solve my problem (if at all it can be solved as I want). But you gave me an idea that would solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CSS **z-index** property only works with ***---sibling elements---***

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="a1"></div>
</div>
<div class="b">
</div>
```

In the above HTML snippet, setting **z-index** to classes a and b will maintain the **z-index** but child **a1** inside class **a** will always remain on top of **a**. So, when **z-index** of class **b** is equal or more than class of sibling **a**, any children of **a** will not go on top of div **b**.